# Animate a div out of window/view with jQuery, css rules ignored on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have an absolute positioned div positioned as follows:

```
#myDiv {
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
height: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

#myDiv {
top: 200%;
}

}
```

The idea being that it is out of the view below 768px window width.

I animate the div into view with jQuery animate with a button when the window width < 768px:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({
top: "0%"
},350);
```

I then animate it back out of the view with another button, again when window width < 768px:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({
    top: "200%"
    },350);
```

If `#myDiv` has been animated out of the view (top:200%) and I resize the window above 768px width,  the css rule `top:0%` is ignored. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not being ignored, but rather over-written. This is because [jQuery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function modifies the inline style of the element which takes precedence over any css rules.

the `!important` modifier in css will tell your inline-style to not take precedence.

```
top: 0% !important;
```

However this won't work because it will also overwrite `top: 200%` in your animate function.

You could listen for [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) changes.

Or you could simply handle the animation by toggling classes instead.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  #myDiv {
    top: 200%;
    transition: top 0.35s
  }

  #myDiv.visible {
    top: 0%
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$('#myDiv').addClass('visible')
```